# Managing URL with Multiple Parameters in Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console, url-parameters

I have launched a new site that was a mobile-friendly redesign of the old site. There are a couple parameters and a session id in the URL (below):

mysite.com/products/product-name/;jsessionid=8XSWXSCnqHZ2mpIYz2xDRRJR.prod-14?f=p%3A25-50&p=2

f= narrows your search by price/rating

p= paginates

jsessionid is the session id for the user

I added all 3 parameters in Webmaster tools (see attached), but the parameters in the URLs are still getting picked up, and it doesn't show any URLs being monitored. Any suggestions/ideas?

[image: Webmaster Tools Screenshot]